# Hide rows in PySimpleGUI table (sg.Table)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have extracted data from a JSON file and built a simple table with PySimpleGUI. The data is a collection of registers and each register has one or more fields as nested data. In a situation like below I have 3 registers with 6 total fields so my table has 9 rows. (There are a lot more columns in the real thing.)

| Name | Fields | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| registerA |  | Stuff here |
|  | field1 | Details here |
|  | field2 | More details |
| registerB |  | More stuff |
|  | field1 | New details |
| registerC |  | Even more |
|  | field1 | New new dets |
|  | field2 | And more |

I'm trying to figure out how to hide the fields to just show the registers, making the fields optional. The ideal situation would be to show/hide fields on a register by register basis by clicking a + or arrow next to each register name, but I'll settle for doing all of them in the table at once with a global on/off switch.

I've seen a few posts about hiding columns, but it's always hiding a specific one column. In this case I need rows (which may be different) and I need something more dynamic where multiple rows may be assigned to a group to hide. Almost like I need a table sub-object for each register row.

Comment: Try the sg.Tree element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show your table in a tree structure, `sg.Tree` maybe good for it.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_key():
    global key
    while key in treedata.tree_dict:
        key += 1
    return key

def build_tree(treedata, data, parent=''):
    for name, description, children in data:
        key = new_key()
        treedata.insert(parent, key, name, [description])
        build_tree(treedata, children, key)

headings = ['Description']
data = [
    ['registerA', 'Stuff here', [['field1', 'Details here', []], ['field2', 'More details', []]]],
    ['registerB', 'More stuff', [['field1', 'New details', []]]],
    ['registerC', 'Even more', [['field1', 'New new dets', []], ['field2', 'And more', []]]],
]

key = 0
treedata = sg.TreeData()
build_tree(treedata, data)

layout = [
    [sg.Tree(data=treedata, headings=headings, col0_heading='Name',
        auto_size_columns=False, num_rows=10, col0_width=20, col_widths=[20],
        justification='left', show_expanded=False, enable_events=True,
        key='-TREE-')],
]

window = sg.Window('Tree Element Test', layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

window.close()
```

[image]